# php oci_fetch_assoc() gives white screen with big data set

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter-2, oci8

I am using php_oci8 module with codeigniter to fetch data from Oracle.

When I fetch a data set > 80,000 records the browser runs for about 20 seconds then stops with no error message just a white screen.

The connection is working just fine for small to medium queries <50,000 records.

I have set error_reporting(E_ALL);

If I was running out of memory, I would expect PHP to throw an error, but the PHP log also shows no errors.

Comment: `set_time_limit(0);`?

Comment: What @Bulk said or `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`

Comment: I already have max execution time set to 20 minutes because some of the data processing we do can take a long time. If execution time was an issue, codeigniter would flag error in a big orange error box. However I did try your suggestion anyway but still get the error.

Comment: Probably the browser closes the connection?

Comment: Hm. What webserver/php implementation are you using? Perhaps it's some sort of gateway timeout? I've had similar things happen when using PHP-FPM for example.

Comment: Think, I might have solved the issue. I started stripping some where in and where not in statements out of the SQL and now it works. I might just have to live with the extra data and filter it at the application level.